# For In como incremento dos valores de un JSON Array pero que se muestren?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles, foreach

tengo una duda sobre este bucle

```
var c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for(var j=0;j<c.length;j++){
console.log(c[j]);};
```

si lo pongo de esta manera

```
var c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for(var j=0;j<c.length;j+=2){
console.log(c[j]);};
```

me incrementa de dos, pero lo que quiero saber es si hay forma que en ves de incrementarlo me tire dos valores en el mismo console.log de esta manera

```
console.log(c[j],c[j]); 
//0 1
//2 3
```

y asi sucesivamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estas buscando recorrer un JSON Array, este ejemplo te puede ayudar, la respuesta per sé, ya te la dió **@phpMyGuel**

Complemento lo que estas buscando

```js
let json = [
{ name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Gates'},
{ name: 'Steve', lastname: 'Jobs'},
{ name: 'Elon', lastname: 'Musk'},
{ name: 'Larry', lastname: 'Page'},
{ name: 'Sergey', lastname: 'Brin'},
{ name: 'Guido', lastname: 'Van Roseum'},
{ name: 'Rasmus', lastname: 'Lerdof'},
{ name: 'James', lastname: 'Gosling'},
{ name: 'Yukihiro ', lastname: 'Matsumoto'},
{ name: 'Sandra', lastname: 'Lerner'}];

for( let i = 0; i < json.length; i+=2 ) {
 let person_one = json[ i ];
 let person_two = json[ i + 1 ];
 console.log( `Persona uno: ${ person_one.name } ${ person_one.lastname } /
 Persona dos: ${ person_two.name } ${ person_two.lastname }`);
}
```

Comment: excelente hermano, examente lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 3):

Podrías acceder al índice actual del bucle y al índice actual + 1 para mostrarlo en el mismo `console.log`. Luego te restaría modificar el índice para que continúe recorriendo el `array` saltándose el índice + 1 que ya imprimiste en el `console.log` (para que no te imprima 0 1, 1 2, 2 3, 4 5...)

```js
var c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

for(var j=0; j < c.length; j++) {
  console.log(c[j] + ' ' + c[j+1]);
  j++;
};
```

Comment: excelente respuesta amigo, pero utilizare un JSON Array para esto y puse ese ejemplo para forma sencilla,  utilice algo parecido ( var c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    for(var j=0;j<c.length;j++){
    console.log(c[j++],c[j]);};   )  y funciona igual pero me gustaria que fuera algo parecido a una declaracion en una variable ya que como utilizare un JSON array tendre muchos valores